# unexpected semicolon or newline before else even though there is neither before else if

Tags: go

I'm trying to fix these errors in my golang code and if someone could help me with that, I'd appreciate it.

Here is my code: http://play.golang.org/p/yELWfIdWz5

Although, the one that is troubling me the most is the first one on line 21 where the error says: syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline before else. I can't find a semicolon or new line on or just before line 21 at all.

Also, what do the errors on line 28 and 32 mean ( non-declaration statement outside function body )-- those statements are in the main() function and the last closing brace closes that function so why is there an error there.

I have a feeling that all of these errors are due to the first one.

I'd greatly appreciate any and all help in resolving these or at least learning more about them.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var current_mid = ""
    current_topic := make(map[string][]string)
    f, err := os.Open(*inputFile)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    xmlFile, _ := os.Create("freebase.xml")
    line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    for err == nil{
        subject, predicate, object := parseTriple(line)
        if subject == current_mid{
            current_topic[predicate] = append(current_topic[predicate], object)
        }
        else if len(current_mid) > 0{
            processTopic(current_mid, current_topic, xmlFile)
            current_topic = make(map[string][]string)
        }
        current_mid = subject
        line, err = r.ReadString('\n')
    }
    processTopic(current_mid, current_topic, xmlFile)
    if err != io.EOF {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
 }
```

Comment: Put your code in the page in case the link dies :)

Comment: @Edward thanks for reminding me to do that. Do you have any idea on how to fix any of these?

Comment: You need to put the 'else' on the line with the close brace in Go. The error can be confusing, but 'newline before else' just refers to the newline after the } on the previous line.

Comment: Hmm, not really I'm a php dev just passing through... could try removing the else if and just have 'if' see if you get the same error

Comment: @twotwotwo oh, wow. Thanks. I thought I could change it as per my style of coding like in other languages.

Comment: Go is super picky about lots of aspects of style (see http://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code), and, right, in this case a standard style isn't just strongly encouraged it's compiler-enforced.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to put the 'else' on the line with the close brace in Go.

Go inserts a ; at the end of lines ending in certain tokens including }; see [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons). That means that, fortunately, it can insert the ending semicolon on x := func(){...} or x := []int{1,2,3}, but it also means it inserts one after the } closing your if block. Since if {...} else {...} is a single compound statement, you can't stick a semicolon in the middle of it after the first }, hence the requirement to put `} else {` on one line

It's unusual, but it keeps the semicolon-insertion behavior simple. Having been hit with unexpected program behavior because of the cleverer semicolon insertion rules in another semicolon-optional language, this seems alright in the scheme of things.

And I can see how the error message was confusing, but 'newline before else' just refers to the newline after the } on the previous line.

Comment: Thanks, this is such a weird compiler error talking about a semicolon when there are no semicolons.

Comment: Hm, I see it a bit weird - compiler is **guessing** where statement has finished, but what if developer intentions was totally different, than that compiler guess ? Of course I understand language designers that their goal was nice - to free developer from unneeded typing of semicolons or even parentheses in conditional branches. But you can't free developer from everything, there is a price of it,- which in some cases may be changing program semantics. So I would opt for omitting automatic injection of semicolons in future Go releases.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Note the rules about when a semicolon is implied are in the language reference and relatively simple: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons . Of course, everyone's free to have their opinions about features.

Comment: I'm not saying that rules are bad or something. Problem is that rules and language specifications have tendency to change in the future. Now, if these semicolon injection rules will change in the future - that may break old go programs semantics. But agree, many things may be not backwards-compatible, so maybe my worries does not count. Anyway, I would prefer put semicolons myself 

Answer (score -1):

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if

You can find the explanation here, but I find it to be a bit bikeshedding. For example, this, unintuitive as it is, compiles:

```
    if your_age >= 16 {
    say("\n You can earn a Drivers License."); } else
    if your_age >= 18 { say("\n You can vote."); } else
    { say("\n You can have fun."); }
```