# Function won't work with if else statements

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a basic cache system with Go as a tutorial.

For some reason when I run this, the if else statement leads to a error.

```
package datasource

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/patrickmn/go-cache"
    "time"
)

type DataSource interface {
    Value(key string) (interface{}, error)

}

// DataSourceStr type, implements the DataSource interface
type DataSourceStr struct {
    data map[string]string
}


var cache = cache.New(5*time.Minute, 5*time.Minute)


func (n *DataSourceStr) Value(key string) (interface{}, error) {
        /* 
    1. Compute a cache key
    2. Search cache key
    3. If hit return value
    4. If miss, do datasource
    5. Cache and return slow thing.
    */
    
    cached, found := cache.Value(key)
    if found {
        return cached, nil
    }

    else if _, ok := n.data[key]; ok 
    {
        //measure how often a key gets called.
        cache.Set(key, n.data[key], cache.DefaultExpiration)
        return n.data[key], nil
    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("key not found %v", ok)
    }
}




func getFromDS(datasource DataSource, key string) (string, error) {

    
    v, err := datasource.Value(key)
    
    //create a map that decays based on time.

    if err != nil {
        return "", nil
    }

    return fmt.Sprint(v), nil
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to have a key entered, then return the value from either the cache or the database. Not sure what I've done wrong with the syntax!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unexpected semicolon or newline before else even though there is neither before else if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371645/unexpected-semicolon-or-newline-before-else-even-though-there-is-neither-before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go conditional statements  follows the following syntax

```
   if something{
      ......

   } else if something{
      ......

   } else{
      ......
   }
```

[a detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371645/unexpected-semicolon-or-newline-before-else-even-though-there-is-neither-before)